# Counting all the differences in 2 dictionaries and displaying them all

Tags: python, dictionary, difference, counting

Suppose I have 2 dictionaries:

```
A = {'banana':10, 'apple':2, 'pear':5, 'orange':3}  
B = {'banana':7, 'orange':5, 'strawberry':4, 'blueberry':1, 'kiwi':10}
```

Now, I need to print all the difference of these dictionaries and display them all (even if there is a key in `A` that is not in `B` or otherwise) and of course in absolute values, so the result should be:

```
c = {'banana':3, 'apple':2, 'pear':5, 'orange':2, 'strawberry':4, 'blueberry':1, 'kiwi':10}
```

Any ideas? I've seen some posts before but only partial answers to this need.

Answer (score 7):

Using [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

A = {'banana':10, 'apple':2, 'pear':5, 'orange':3}
B = {'banana':7, 'orange':5, 'strawberry':4, 'blueberry':1, 'kiwi':10}

A_Counter, B_Counter = Counter(A), Counter(B)

print((A_Counter - B_Counter) | (B_Counter - A_Counter))
```

Output:

```
Counter({'kiwi': 10, 'pear': 5, 'strawberry': 4, 'banana': 3, 'apple': 2, 'orange': 2, 'blueberry': 1})
```

Comment: The output itself is not a dictionary I guess? Since it contains Counter({...})?

Comment: @Nate: According to the documentation (see the link above), "A Counter is a dict subclass" and "the usual dictionary methods are available for Counter objects except for two" (fromkeys and update) "which work differently for counters". In other words, it behaves like a simple dictionary 97% of the time.

Answer (score 4):

In py2x `A.viewkeys() | B.viewkeys()` will return the union of keys from both `A` & `B`, and then you can use a dict comprehension to get the desired result.

```
In [14]: A = {'banana':10, 'apple':2, 'pear':5, 'orange':3}

In [15]: B = {'banana':7, 'orange':5, 'strawberry':4, 'blueberry':1, 'kiwi':10}

In [16]: {x : abs( A.get(x,0) - B.get(x,0) )  for x in A.viewkeys() | B.viewkeys()}
Out[16]: 
{'apple': 2,
 'banana': 3,
 'blueberry': 1,
 'kiwi': 10,
 'orange': 2,
 'pear': 5,
 'strawberry': 4}
```

For py3x use : `A.keys() | B.keys()`

For both py2x and py3x: `set(A).union(B)`

Comment: You can use `A.viewkeys() | B.viewkeys()` to get a union of keys from the two dictionaries without the intermediary set creation. See [Dictionary view objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I knew about them, but didn't use them because `viewkeys` only work in py2x, for py3x we have to use `.keys()`.

Comment: I usually mention that explicitly, depending on the tags on the question.